# RewriteMap Directive (permanent or temp redirect?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This may sound like a silly question and I'm probably mixing apple with oranges, but please bear with me.

I'm reading the documentation here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#mapfunc

It says when using an external .txt file the format is a simple key/value pair example:

> fromHere.html      toHere.html

^ I'd like to confirm that the above would create a temp 302 redirect (that browsers won't aggressively cache), or may be I can indicate the type of redirect to be used (301/302) in the actual RewriteRule in the htaccess file? (if so how?)

Currently I use the following syntax inside the .htaccess file itself

> Redirect 302 fromHere.html 
>   toHere.html

Is the above syntax allowed in the external .txt file?

Thank you

Comment: This isn't a programming question, you might be able to find help at [sf]

Comment: lots of questions similar questions SO, so I thought I'd ask here

Comment: Take a look at [help/on-topic]. 'Lots of similar questions' doesn't really make an off-topic question on-topic.

Comment: checked your link then checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server which is a webserver software. So it all checks out. If you have some actual advice about the topic at hand that would be great.

Comment: No, it doesn't check out, there's an entire separate site for this stuff. "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault."

Comment: "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools." it's really right there in black and white. I'm not sure why looking for help in the right place is such a personal affront to you.

Comment: I read half a dozen questions right here on SO that talked about htaccess and apache config. Many answered by senior members and I haven't come across a single comment that talk about the question being in a wrong section, none with votes to be closed etc. About personal affront: I get an immediate downvote right after you comment and it's obvious that you're the one downvoting the helpful answer below for no good reason, so I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: @pvg The ".htaccess" tag has [just under 60,000 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess), the "mod-rewrite" tag has [just under 30,000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite). Clearly these are considered valid here. You should take up your concerns in Meta. The community has clearly spoken on this. And while we're quoting rules, "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." which does not include "because you consider it off-topic".

Comment: And in fact [it specifically says](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) "**Instead of voting down**: ... If the question is duplicate or off-topic, flag it for moderator attention." So your tirade is just that, and not based on the spirit, or the letter, of the rules here in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RewriteMap` won't create any kind of redirect by itself. You use a `RewriteMap` in a `RewriteRule`, and the format that you use for the `RewriteRule` will define what kind of redirect it generates. You're looking at documentation for Apache 2.0 there, which is old. The current version is 2.4.

Here is [the current documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html). To generate a 302 redirect, you would do something like:

```
RewriteMap examplemap "txt:/path/to/file/map.txt"
RewriteCond ${examplemap:$1} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ${examplemap:$1} [L,R=302]
```

Which says look up the full request in the `RewriteMap`, and if it exists, redirect to it as a 302.

Comment: Great stuff. The answer was incomplete when you saw it as I submitted it before finishing by mistake, please check it again just to make sure you got all the info.

Comment: yep, it's the last line with the actual 301, 302 directive that was confusing me. It was part of the original answer. New answer is good too, thank you

Comment: Yeah, and the important thing is to have the `RewriteCond` before it, or it will redirect anything whether it's in the map or not, which is what I hadn't added originally. You could also add a forward slash before the `${examplemap:$1}` or put that in your map.

Comment: Finally, the map needs to be in your Apache config as you probably know, but the other code is written for .htaccess. If you do it all in your Apache config then you also need to have the opening forward slash or they won't match. .htaccess doesn't include the opening forward slash in the match.